# Visual Studio Django - Freezes on python manage.py createsuperuser

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, manage.py

So, I'm new to Django and am using Visual Studio 2022 with Python 3.12 (which is apparently not fully supported by Visual Studio).

When I start a fresh Django web app project, it prompts for me to create a super user. Doing so, it freezes (without any error message) as it executes "manage.py createsuperuser" (as shown in screenshot). Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to type an admin username like `"bob"` with quotes ?

Comment: Tried that. Stays frozen, now with the blue spinning wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried executing the command with `python3 manage.py runserver`? It may have something to do with the Python version you are using to run the command.

Alternatively, you could try to run the command on the standard terminal for the OS you are using as opposed to the vs code terminal

Comment: Thanks. I switched over to VS Code and don't have the issue anymore. I don't think Visual Studio (currently) is a great fit for Django.